# Error, region type missing in..? What is this?

Tags: python, scripting

Keep getting this error message amd would really appreciate your help.

[image]

Any idea what this means?

I've edited some of the original code, changed around some of the parameters such as changing the name of the objects. I don't know if that had an effect?

If it did/would, vaguely what can I do to ensure this error message doesn't keep propping up.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: when exactly is this message popping up and which "original code" you changed - do you mean Blender original source code??

Comment: Hey, thanks. The message pops up whenever I run the game engine. I've downloaded some blender script off the internet, created new objects and deleted the original ones, but embedded them into the code. I think this is something to do with it as I was not having the problem prior to changing the objects.

Comment: I'm not even sure what "image", "file" and "action" refer to. I cannot see them in the addon script, and no object is called any of those names.
I'm a fetus when it comes to scripting- I understand if this is somewhat infuriating.

Comment: Strongly suggest posting a link to (or) the source code somewhere.  My guess is it's a print statement in said code.

Comment: @batFINGER thank you! I seem to have sorted it out now and ran into a new problem, haha :D

Answer (score 1):

The blender system is structured with Area's [1](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html) and Regions [2](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/regions.html).

**Area**

The application window is always a rectangle on your desktop. It is divided up into a number of re-sizable areas. An area contains the workspace for a particular type of editor, like a 3D View Editor, or an Outliner.

**Region**

An area is divided into regions (a sort of placeholders). For example:

- Header
- Main
- Tool Shelf
- Properties
- etc

Scripts can use these regions to (for example) add custom panels to a region.

**Now the Error**

The message `Error, region type missing in - name` is send to the console when a script wants to access a region in a area for temporary windows.

This used to happen when users open a user-prefs or render window (those are temporary screen and). And then start using it as a regular window (split it, change space types... etc). This was solved in 2015, but could still be possible when scripting.

Comment: Could you please provide a small  sample script which produces this error?